# How do i add 3 dots instead of the arrow between S2 and S3?

Tags: smartdiagram

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usesmartdiagramlibrary{additions}

\begin{document}
    \smartdiagramset{uniform sequence color=true,sequence item border color=black,sequence item font size=\footnotesize, sequence item text color=white}
    \begin{center}
        \smartdiagram[flow diagram:horizontal]{$ S_{1} $, $ S_{2} $, $ S_{3} $, $ S_{4} $ }
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome. Tip: To markup code, as I did in my edit, you select the code, and then hit Ctrl + K (or click the button marked `{}`). Blocks are then indented with four spaces, inline code placed between backticks (`\``).